# Hotel early arrival for another guest

Tags: accommodation, check-in

I made a hotel reservation through Expedia under my name for two people but my friend will arrive one day before me. The duration is 8-14. I'm arriving on the 9th, my friend is arriving on the 8th.

So can he check in?

Comment: the duration is 8-14 i'm arriving on the 9th, my friend is arriving on the 8th

Comment: Most hotel rooms allow a second name to be recorded on the reservation, as your situation is not at all uncommon, particularly among couples who do not share a surname. I advise giving the hotel reception a call to explain.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the Hotel, this may or may not be a problem.

I have worked at many different hotels in the US, we need to see an ID with the same name that's on the reservation to check in the room.  I have fudged this rule on occasion (for spouses, siblings or children who can produce an ID with the same *last name*).

It would be safer to call the hotel ahead of time and add another name to the reservation.  Most PMSs support multiple names on a reservation, so you should be able to keep your name on it as well.

Comment: thanks but the hotel is paid using his credit card.

Comment: If the reservation is under your name, but has his CC is on file, then he has a decent chance of being able to check in without you there.  Showing the front desk the credit card on the reservation certainly demonstrates some connection to the room, but it would still be safer to contact the hotel and straighten everything out with them.

Comment: alright thanks!
just one quick question.. the hotel can see information about the CC used..even if its by expedia? for example the last 4 digits

Comment: Usually, Expedia (and Kayak, Travelocity, etc) will take a payment from the guest, then pay the Hotel (because they often mark up the room slightly), obscuring all payment information in the process.  So no, if you paid through Expedia, there is a good chance the Hotel will NOT have access the the credit card information.  Usually the reservation that the front desk will see says "EXPEDIA PAYMENT" or something like that in the payment method section.

Comment: i contacted the hotel, they said to send them the reservation number, is that the same as the itinerary number that shows on expedia?

Comment: Most hotels try to simplify things be having the hotel's reservation number and the Expedia confirmation number be the same.  If their system does not support this, they usually have a way to associate the two by adding notes to the reservation.  So yes, your Expedia number *should* be connected to your reservation so they can find it.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you have booked one room under your name, but your friend will arrive first. This could be a problem. To prevent fraud, many hotels insist on seeing a credit card with a name matching the name on the reservation, especially when the reservation has been booked through a third-party booking site like Expedia.

I would contact the hotel in advance to ask about their procedures; ideally get a response in writing. In many cases, you can complete in advance a credit card authorization form provided by the hotel, to be carried by your friend, which the hotel will accept as proof.

Comment: +1 for contacting the hotel. They know their check-in rules, and may be able to make an exception if discussed in advance.

Answer (score 2):

He will not be able to check in since the reservation does not contain his name. You should call the hotel and change the reservation to include his name.